# Java Synchronized (int) is possible?

Tags: java, synchronized

```
class Banco{

    int slots;
    int []av;

    public Banco(int n){
        slots = n;
        av=new int[slots];
        for(int i=0;i<slots;i++)
            av[i]=0;

    }

    public int query(int i){
            return this.av[i];

    }

    public int getSlots (){
        return this.slots;
    }

    public synchronized void credito(int i, int valor){
        av[i] += valor;
    }

    public synchronized void debito(int i, int valor){
        av[i] -= valor;
    }

    public void transferir(int valor){
        Random r = new Random();

        int a = r.nextInt(slots);
        int b = r.nextInt(slots);

        if(a<b){
            synchronized(this.query(a)){
                synchronized(this.query(b)){
                    this.credito(b,valor);
                    this.debito(b,valor);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            a = r.nextInt(slots);
            b = r.nextInt(slots);
        }

    }
}
```

This is my code, but on synchronized I get the following error I do not know why:

unexpected type
            synchronized(this.query(a))

required: reference

found:    int

error: unexpected type
                synchronized(this.query(b))

required: reference

found:    int

Comment: No it isn't. You can't synchronize on a primitive.

Comment: as the error message indicates, it's not possible.  It has to be an `Object`

Comment: ok, that was my doubt, thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is almost certainly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @AndyTurner I like the implementation of `query` the most ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize on an Integer but not on an int. I fail to see why you would want to synchronize on a value though. Usually you'll synchronize on an object created just for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll need to elaborate on @bruno’s answer.

In Java, everything non-primitive is a subclass of `Object`. An `Integer`
is a thin wrapper around `int`. it has a value, and you can use the same basic arithmetic on it. But it lives on the heap and is almost always passed as a reference, not a copy of the value. If you replace the `int` with `Integer`, the synchronisation will work.

**However**, it would be better to consider why you’re trying to synchronise an `int` and consider other options, for example any of the [atomic operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html). In general synchronised blocks are less performant and while they can enforce a happens-before relationship, you often don’t need it, if we’re talking about a single integer.